# woocommerce fake file for download where no file exists

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i have a woocommerce shop and provide digital goods.

WOO provide a method to overwrite the path (woocommerce_download_product_filepath) over this i can provide the data.

The problem: this works only when the product has a file added and the name for this file is used.

Im looking now for a way i can set the "fake file" on fly like a filter a filename/url without permanent save

I have no code i can provide, i was looking inside /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes but saw no direct function which is called.(in my tests the functions where looks nice are only called on products with files)

for permanent set i could use a hook which is triggered before the post is saved and add the data but would prefer a on fly method on runtime.